# form submit jQuery function doesn't work in js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

i have a MVC View when i use form sumbit function inside my view its work fine. but when i put my code insde the js file its stop working

why is that? and is there a solution?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content( "~/Scripts/site/js.js" )" ></script>
@using( Html.BeginForm( "Index" , "Sample" , FormMethod.Post , new { id = "frm" } ) )
{
    <div>
        <p>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('form').submit(function ()  // or $('#frm').submit
        {
            alert('1');
            return false;
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"?

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals : i mean its not fired. and that **alert('1')** does not showing

Comment: Does the code sample you posted work or not? Also, would you post the other working/non-working code sample? And, you you using asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your external file, try wrapping it in a `$(document).ready();` call. So

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#frm').submit(function ()
        {
            alert('1');
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Also, I assume this is obvious, but remove the inline JS, too, when using the external js. :-)

Comment: i ask the question for removing that inline js

Comment: I'm sorry, that doesn't make any sense to me. The goal of my post was to point out that you should try using `$(document).ready();` in your external javascript. Additionally, if you're using an external javascript file, then you'll want to be sure you remove your inline javascript to avoid conflicts/cleanliness. Make sense?

Comment: i want to remove any js inside my view and only use my external js file. if i say it wrong sorry. its for my bad english

Comment: In that case, my code should work in your external file. No worries - thanks for clarifying. :-)